# cmake .. not found package

Tags: development

I'm try to build and install Photos, but `cmake` give me an error:

`No package 'geocode-glib-1.0' found`

Already try to install try to install `libgeocode-glib0`.
Then install `libgeocode-glib-dev` and give me

`A required package was not found`

but without package name.

EDIT:
I'm able to create a simple vala application and run with
`valac-0.34 --pkg geocode-glib-1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours trying and learning cmake basics I found it that a lot of packages searched by `pkg_check_modules` needs -dev dependencies. So I manually installed all missing dev packages.

Comment: Is it your answer? If yes, you don't need to add another question at the end of it. If no, it shouldn't be in answer section